# Groovy version number count up?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i have a problem with a version number that i want to increment in a Jenkins script.

Unfortunately the variable containing the version is linked to a letter, so the output is : `v1`

Now I want to count down the version with -1

> v1 with -1

in this case I would like to have the variable

```
v2
```

How can I increment a number that has a letter ?

Answer (score 1):

You can treat strings like lists. So this should work:

```
def version = "v1"
def versionNumber = version[1..-1] as int

version = "v${versionNumber + 1}"
```

Comment: Will this work once you get to double digits? I wonder if `version[1..-1]` mightn’t be more robust?